# Forcefully close http connection in golang

Tags: http, go

My program downloads a file from one server and then returns it to the user. Here is snippet of it:

```
// Make get request to target server
resp, httpErr := http.Get(url.String()) 

// Return error if http request is failed 
if httpErr != nil {
    fmt.Fprintln(w,"Http Request Failed :" ,httpErr.Error())
    return
}

//Setting up headers
w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+vid.Title+"."+format.Extension)
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", r.Header.Get("Content-Type"))
w.Header().Set("Content-Length", strconv.Itoa(int(resp.ContentLength)))

// Copy instream of resp.Body to writer
io.Copy(w, resp.Body)
```

When the user stops the download or closes the connection I want to close the GET connection as well. 
But it does not get closed as I found via usage graph. How can I close the connection of the user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should close the `Body` of the request in any case:

```
resp, httpErr := http.Get(url.String())
if httpErr != nil {
   // handle error
   return
}
// if it's no error then defer the call for closing body
defer resp.Body.Close()
```

More should not be necessary to do. When the client closes the connection `io.Copy` returns with an error. `io.Copy` returns the number of bytes written and an error. You could check that, if you want to know if the copy succeded.

```
written, err := io.Copy(w, resp.Body)
if err != nil {
    // Copy did not succeed
}
```